# Lost PATH variable content

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, scripts

I was trying to add something to the PATH with :

```
export PATH=/user/home/sbt/bin
```

but I removed all of the content of PATH and I can not run any command on the terminal even ls ! So what should I do ? Can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`? This will only work for the actual session.

Comment: Thank you @Lucio it helped me, but is there any way to undo to the old content ?

Comment: Did the method of the answer below worked for you?

Comment: Also, to know what paths do you have, enter `cat /etc/environment` in a terminal.

Comment: @Lucio, after log out and log in the below worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the terminal app, and open a new one. The variable will be reset to its original state then.

If you're on a virtual terminal, and not running gnome-terminal or similar under X11, then you can log out and log back in again, to reset the variables. You can type `exit` to log out, or press Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the [answer by dobey](https://askubuntu.com/a/272376/593911) doesn't work for you.

Follow these steps to recover the PATH environment variable :

- Delete the culprit file from /etc/profile.d/ (if any)
- Delete the culprit line from /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc (if any)
- Execute `source /etc/environment` to start reseting the path environment variable
- Execute `source /etc/profile` followed by `source /etc/profile.d/*`
- At last `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

For you case you could Use command: export *PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/user/home/sbt/bin*

then use command *sudo gedit /etc/environment*  delete whatever it is in then copy and paste this 
*PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/user/home/sbt/bin"*

finally run a command *source /etc/environment*

Now you should be fine